# Camera Renders Floor very badly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I tried to render an image of my scene yesterday, and I did. It rendered really good for the most part, but the floor looked really really really stretched and it just look very bad, I tried to see it in rendered viewport but it looked fine, I tried changing the focal length but that led to my viewport being messed up. Also, I've rendered this using cycles and Blender version 3.10 Alpha I've tried changing where the camera is, I have tried changing the amount of samples, and I have tried adding a new camera and see if it did the same thing but nothing seemed to fix the problem. Here is a link to the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzcr3gatmiipd86/WalkingAnimation.blend?dl=0
EDIT: I have fixed the dropbox link.

And here is the rendered image:
[image]

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Your blend file link leads to a page that says "This Item was deleted." Try https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @HISEROD I have fixed the link issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever something appears in a render but doesn't appear in the viewport, the first thing you want to check for are objects that have been hidden in the viewport but are still enabled in the render.  In the outliner, you'll see that several of your "Plane" objects are hidden in the viewport (closed eye) but still enabled in the render (filled camera icon), like so:

[image]

You'll either want to click the camera icons to disable these in the render or, better yet, move them all into some disabled collection.

Comment: Buhr Hi Buhr, thanks for the reply, I didn't realize that the planes were hidden, thanks for helping me solve my problem.